# whatwg-fetch response.ok === true even if server is offline

Tags: javascript, fetch

I make requests using [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) and I'm trying to check `response.status === 0` in case `response.ok` is false to see if the server is currently offline and notify users accordingly.

Problem is, `response.status` is always 200 and `response.ok` is always true when the server's offline.

```
const interpretJsonResponse = (response, callback):object => {
    const responseClone = response.clone();
    if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((json) => callback(null, respondJson(json))).catch(callback);
    } else {
        //  Response is not ok. Callback with a generic error to show to the user
        //  and log the error for detailed info
        if (response.status === 0) {
            //  Backend server is not up
            callback('Backend server is not responding. Please retry later!');
        } else {
            callback(`Error in request: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    }

    // Return a clone to allow usage of .json() again if necessary
    return responseClone;
};
```

I'm also getting a JSON parse error since the response is empty, given the lack of servers to reply. What am I / could I be missing?

Example Response object:

```
"url":"http://localhost:8000/client_v1/auth/",
"status":200,
"statusText":"OK",
"headers": {}
"ok":true,
"body":{  
   "_readableState":{  
      "highWaterMark":16384,
      "buffer":[],
      "length":0, 
      "pipes":null,
      "pipesCount":0,
      "flowing":null,
      "ended":false,
      "endEmitted":false,
      "reading":false,
      "sync":false,
      "needReadable":true,
      "emittedReadable":false,
      "readableListening":false,
      "objectMode":false,
      "defaultEncoding":"utf8",
      "ranOut":false,
      "awaitDrain":0,
      "readingMore":false,
      "decoder":null,
      "encoding":null
  },
  "readable":true,
  "_events":{},
  "_writableState":{  
     "highWaterMark":16384,
     "objectMode":false,
     "needDrain":false,
     "ending":false,
     "ended":false,
     "finished":false,
     "decodeStrings":true,
     "defaultEncoding":"utf8",
     "length":0,
     "writing":false,
     "corked":0,
     "sync":true,
     "bufferProcessing":false,
     "writecb":null,
     "writelen":0,
     "buffer":[  

     ],
     "pendingcb":0,
     "prefinished":false,
     "errorEmitted":false
  },
  "writable":true,
  "allowHalfOpen":true,
  "_transformState":{  
     "needTransform":false,
     "transforming":false,
     "writecb":null,
     "writechunk":null
  }
},
"bodyUsed":false,
"size":0,
"timeout":0,
"_raw":[],
"_abort":false
```

EDIT: Added full function
EDIT #2: Added example whatwg-fetch Response object

Comment: What is the fetch statement? Normally, when fetch promise is resolved, 2 function will be passed: one is success handler and another is error handler. If the server is offline, then success handler ("interpretJsonResponse") will never be called. Only error handler is invoked and passed with an error object.

Comment: While I agree completely, `interpretJsonResponse` is where it fails, specifically at the `response.json()` bit where it attempts to JSON.parse(undefined).

Answer (score 0):

I just found this caveat, in [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch), which could be useful to you:

```
Caveats

The fetch specification differs from jQuery.ajax() in mainly two ways that bear keeping in mind:

The Promise returned from fetch() won't reject on HTTP error status even if the response is a HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally, and it will only reject on network failure, or if anything prevented the request from completing.
```

So, I should simply check the response for emptyness (if response is empty, as you say):

```
if (response === null) {
  return callback('Empty reponse from backend server. Please retry later!');
}
if (response.ok) {
  ...
```

Comment: The response supplied by the server is marked as (failed) in the network tab of the developer tools. There is no response to be shown in its Response subtab, and I also get net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Nevertheless, the response object should never actually be null, it should just have an empty body, a status of false and an appropriate code. The saddest part is that, apart from module updates, I don't see what could have broken this functionality that used to work.

Comment: If it worked differently on previous versions, probably it was just the fetch module update (or some of its dependencies) to break up. However, I agree the response object should never actually be null, but, if it is, you have two choices: (one) adapt your code to the modules it depends on (`fetch`), and implement my check, or (two) check the modules sources, and post an issue if you find any error, and eventually fork the original module if you get no answer (it has happened to me sometimes... :-().